# date and time format for x axis in gnuplot

Tags: time, gnuplot

I have a csv file that looks like:

> 1,Fri Jun 27 23:22:17 2014
>
> ...
>
> 3500,Sat Jun 28 09:21:55 2014

I want to plot column 1 as y and column 2 as x:

```
set datafile separator ","
set xdata time
set timefmt "%a %b %d %T %Y"
set format x "%d-%b\n%H:%M"
plot "file.csv" u 2:1
```

For every line I get an error:

```
warning: Bad time format in string
warning: Bad abbreviated month name
warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
```

And at the end x range is invalid

I really do not know what is going on. My time format looks good. Right?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnuplot does not support the `%a`, `%T` specifiers in `timefmt` (nevertheless, they can be used in `set format x`) - see p. 168 in the [documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf).

While `%T` can be directly replaced with `%H:%M:%S`, `%a` might seem a bit problematic. A workaround would be to preprocess the file in order to get rid of the day name in the second column, e.g.

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"
set format x "%d-%b\n%H:%M"
plot "<(gawk -F, '{print $1, substr($2, 5)}' file.csv)" u 2:1
```

Note that since the file was preprocessed by `gawk`, the command `set datafile separator ","` is no longer needed here.

Comment: Ok. I have to remove the "Fri" or "Sat" word from the files (easy with vim). I get the warnings `Bad abbreviated month name` and the plot :)
 Thanks

Comment: @murpholinox so the `Bad abbreviated month name` error persists? this might suggest that the abbreviations in your file are in a language which is not compatible with your system locale - perhaps `set locale ""` at the beginning of the Gnuplot script might help...